# Take up arms quest glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

i used magic against Vilkas when trying to enter 'the companions'. Now he won't acknowledge my melee attacks. I can't go into any shop menus, complete quests or talk properly. I used up all my autosaves trying to fix it. Now I have to start all over again, I was level 27 and very far through the main quest!

I've tried getting a bounty and paying it off, but conversations never trigger anything. I tried sleeping, going to jail (no trigger), hitting Vilkas with both shield and sword then sheathing etc. and he is indestructible so I can't kill him.

I might just put the game down until Bethesda patch this, which may mean I will never pick it back up. Shame.

If anyone can think of any other way to fix this I would be indebted. I refuse to start again.

Maybe if there is an alternate way to complete the quest? I heard there are a few ways of getting in to the companions.

Comment: Hm weird,I also used magic but i believe i hit him once or twice with sword that could make the difference.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I loaded the autosave from when I was following him out to the training grounds and that fixed mine, but if you used all your autosaves after it glitched then I guess your screwed

Comment: happened to me as well and i couldn't load a savegame. so i finished the whole "take up arms" quest (deliver the sword, deliver the shield and follow to the quarters) being followed by the hostile vilkas and after finishing the quest vilkas wasn't hostile anymore. phew... and i thought i had to start a whole new game...

Comment: Same thing here, but I am using it to my advance at the moment. Keep leveling up my skills byt hitting on him round after round. Nice to know, I will never trade this game for anything new on GameStop, so I dont care, I will join the Companions on a later playtrough. -Soap-

Comment: You need to attack Vilkas with a sword or mace that is not enchanted.

Comment: @Mike How did you get Vilkas' sword to complete the quest? I been trying everything and anything I could find on the internet with nothing work. tried hitting with a glass mace that was not enchanted with no luck. still the same loop over and over. Please Please help if you know anything. And no I cannot Pick Pocket the sword either.

Comment: I have done the same thing with Vilkas use magic to raise level. When i was level 17 i was at the greybeards leveling up sneak. Then i was caught. So I ran outside and the bad thing is i saved right before i died I died by falling. Had only one save. Somehow I got to the map and fast-traveled, which didn't work. I kept doing that, thinking its over, but weirdly enough I was alive going through the mountain. And after that I fast-traveled and i was saved.

Answer (score 1):

requirements for completion:

- Only a melee weapon used (no ranged or spells)
- Weapon not enchanted